# MySQL last_query_cost for complex queries

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-tuning

when trying to find the cost of a complex query (one with a sub-query in it) i get a value of 0. 
[mysql's manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html):

> "The Last_query_cost value can be
>   computed accurately only for simple
>   “flat” queries, not complex queries
>   such as those with subqueries or
>   UNION. For the latter, the value is
>   set to 0."

and my question is - how do i calculate a cost of a complex query?

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to be a h8r, but I'm not convinced in the merit of the 'Last_query_cost'... it just seems to over simplify what the cost of a query really is. Obfuscation for a lack of education. :)

Personally, I pay more attention to the execution path laid out in the EXPLAIN, and the SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler_%' values to see what is actually done.